# SCRIPT1028: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, svg

When I import:

```
import {ReactComponent as Name} from '../assets/name.svg';
```

I get the error, but when I do:

```
import test from '../assets/name.svg';
```

The error goes away.

I've installed the react-polyfills and have imported them at the top of index.js:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Particle from '../Particle/particle';
import {ReactComponent as Name} from '../assets/name.svg';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  // componentDidMount() {
  //   console.log(this.state.points);
  
  // }


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <Particle />
        <div className="name">
         {/* <Name/> */}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

It should be showing the svg Edge, but  I get the error. When i uncomment the component, the page doesn't even load, but works in other browsers

Comment: I am not really sure how an SVG file can contain a react component? An SVG file can have only one default export.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files#adding-svgs.      According to the docs, it's possible. For some reason it's throwing the error only in EDGE/IE